# Get related item

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `User` model and a `Book` model.

Book is declared to `belongs_to :user`.

How do I get all books belonging to a specific user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to declare in User:

```
has_many :books
```

After that you can access it via the ruby console or if you want it in rails you need to create a route in the routes.rb:

```
  resources :books do
    resources :users
  end
```

After that you can ask the controller for all books of one user. 
Just call books on a user in the controller.

And if you somewhere else in your code need all books for a certain user (e.g. @user):

```
@user.books
```